# How to center the login form

Tags: html, css, forms, authentication

Please see the output https://jsbin.com/wofuwefoga/edit?html,css,output

I like my login form to be in the center of the screen without worrying about browser compatibility.

Comment: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: Just keep the login form in a div and do a margin-left.

Answer (score 0):

After this div `.col-lg-12` you can add new div just like `.login_area` and here you go:

```
.login_area{
  margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its not a proper way.....but it can solve your problem

add this line to your css file

```
.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
{
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```